# View User's current logon script without domain admin rights

Tags: active-directory, startup-scripts

Is there a way to view which logon script is running for an AD user without having domain admin rights.

I've tried gpresult and it isn't displaying any login/logoff scripts, but I believe the script is configured under the user's Profile tab in AD Users&Computers.

Are there any events logged I could refer to, or does this logon script get stored locally by chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser MDMarra -Properties scriptpath | Select scriptpath
```

In cmd:

```
dsquery user -samID MDMarra | dsget user -loscr
```

This will return the path of the logon script set in the `Profile` tab of ADUC.

or

Just install ADUC on your workstation and look at the Profile tab for the user in question. You don't need to be a domain admin to view objects in ADUC.

---

By default, you can view this attribute for all users in your domain without having Domain Admin rights.

Comment: Thank you for this, I originally used another VBScript to access the same info, but this worked too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have AD modules installed on your clients, You can use the WMI class as follows:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Select-Object -Property 
ScriptPath
```